# How to append object multiple time to an array

Tags: swift

I want to append all of my object in a single line. I have some object like this:

```
let abaddon = Hero(name: "abaddon")
let ember = Hero(name: "ember")
let gondar = Hero(name: "gondar")
let kael = Hero(name: "kael")
let kunkka = Hero(name: "kunkka")
let layana = Hero(name: "layana")
let lucifer = Hero(name: "lucifer")
let omni = Hero(name: "omni")
let soul = Hero(name: "soul")
let wind = Hero(name: "wind")
```

The Hero Object like so:

```
class Hero {

    var name: String!
    var image: UIImage? {
        return UIImage(named: "\(name)")!
    }

    required init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

And I want to put them to this array: `var heroes = [Hero]()`

But I see `append` only be able to put one object each time.

```
heroes.append(abaddon)
```

How to append multiple objects in single line, something like this:

```
heroes.append([abaddon, ember, gondar])
```

Any helps would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want to append multiple objects, You could wrap them into an array themselves and use appendContentsOf.

```
heroes.append(contentsOf:[abaddon, ember, gondor])
```

Answer (score 7):

I try like this:

```
let heroes = ["abaddon","ember","gondar",etc].map { Hero(name: $0) }
```

So I don't need to declare all objects

Comment: This is smart. You declare the array of names first, then create an array that  contains one new instance of `Hero` for each name on the list.

Comment: If the initializer ever requires more than just a single argument, this will get very messy.

Comment: Yes, if Hero object has more properties, this solution is not convenient anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4.x answer of @TPlet

```
nameField.append(contentsOf: [abaddon, ember, gondor])
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
var heroes = [abaddon, ember, ..., wind]
```

Comment: Because he needs objects of type `Hero`, that likely hold other additional properties/state besides `name`; and array of strings won't do.

Comment: They aren't strings (no quotes around them), they are the actual variable names.

Comment: My bad, missed that.